# jQuery Datatables Pre Render Styling (missing)

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

Is there any work around for the pre-loaded/instantiated to prevent the lack of styling being present before the api loads the table?

Right now for example. The headers of my table are bunched up with no spacing looking like a funky sentence.

**HeadHead1Head2Something**

for example.

I've tried a number of ways to get around this, from how/when I load my table data.. to using the `oLanguage` setting for `processing` to have an image loader, figuring it was maybe lack of content. But no, the style just doesn't appear until after the `$(' selector ').dataTable();` call is made.

Answer (score 1):

you can hide the table before it is initialized and show it after initializing is complete.

Use CSS to hide the table.

```
.grid { display: none; }
```

add fnInitComplete to your datatable settings to show the table once it is intililized.

```
enter code here
$(".grid").dataTable({
 // Your settings
 "fnInitComplete": function(oSettings, json) {
   $(".grid").show()
 }
});
```